# Downloading Image

Tags: python

I used urllib2.build_opener() to download an image from a corresponding url.But for a particular url I am getting an error.  When I checked that url, I saw that there is no image.  How can I check whether there is an image or not?  This is my code:

```
opener1 = urllib2.build_opener()
page1=opener1.open(orginal)
my_picture=page1.read()
```

The error i got is

```
  File "suitcase.py", line 120, in <module>
    get_suitcase()
  File "suitcase.py", line 96, in get_suitcase
    page1=opener1.open(orginal)
  File "D:\Program Files\Python\lib\urllib2.py", line 395, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "D:\Program Files\Python\lib\urllib2.py", line 508, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "D:\Program Files\Python\lib\urllib2.py", line 433, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "D:\Program Files\Python\lib\urllib2.py", line 367, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "D:\Program Files\Python\lib\urllib2.py", line 516, in http_error_default

    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

How do I check that an image is there and proceed with saving that image?

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand. Why just not catch the error with the try and except keywords?

Answer (score 1):

as others have suggested catch the exception and check for code e.g.

```
import urllib2

opener1 = urllib2.build_opener()
try:
    page1=opener1.open("http://www.google.com/nosuchimage")
    my_picture=page1.read()
except urllib2.HTTPError,e:
    if e.code == 404:
        print "no such image"
    else:
        print "error",e
except urllib2.URLError,e:
    print "URLError",e
```

Comment: Thanks....When i tested with the above code it works..but new error shown like this File "/usr/lib/python2.5/httplib.py", line 860, in endheaders self._send_output() File "/usr/lib/python2.5/httplib.py", line 732, in _send_output self.send(msg) File "/usr/lib/python2.5/httplib.py", line 699, in send self.connect() File "/usr/lib/python2.5/httplib.py", line 683, in connect raise socket.error, msg IOError: [Errno socket error] (110, 'Connection timed out') i tried wid the Except IOError but it is not fixed

Comment: are you ure you are using urllib2 ? becuase for timeout it may raise urllib2.URLError ? I have added that too

Answer (score 0):

By checking the `code` attribute of the [exception](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.HTTPError).

Answer (score 0):

```
try:
    page1=opener1.open(orginal)
except HTTPError, e:
    if e.code == 404: # Only one of the many possible errors...
        print "Resource does not exist"
    raise

my_picture=page1.read()
```

see also [urllib2 - the missing manual](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/urllib2.shtml#httperror)

Comment: Thanks....When i tested with the above code it works..but new error shown like this

File "/usr/lib/python2.5/httplib.py", line 860, in endheaders
   self._send_output()
 File "/usr/lib/python2.5/httplib.py", line 732, in _send_output
   self.send(msg)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.5/httplib.py", line 699, in send
   self.connect()
 File "/usr/lib/python2.5/httplib.py", line 683, in connect
   raise socket.error, msg
IOError: [Errno socket error] (110, 'Connection timed out')
 
i tried wid the Except IOError but it is not fixed

Comment: @arung A socket error is very different from a http error. First check with a browser wether "original" is available and downloadable. You should see the image. If that works, you might use the wrong protocol (http / https) or the wrong port (default for http is 80); again, the URL specified in the browser should be retrievable by urllib2.